# Continue once the thread returns true

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, jprogressbar

I am having trouble getting my code to 'pause' until the thread is finished. My program is simply a JProgressBar inside a frame. I am using a loop located inside a thread, which loops every 10 milliseconds and adds +1 to the progress bar. The end result will make the bar look animated as its value increases from 0 to 100.

Now, the problem is getting the code to 'wait' until the progress bar hits value 100. As you can see in the code, I would like to have buttons re-enabled **only when** the progress bar reaches value 100. As of right now, the buttons seem to get re-enabled simultaneously as the progress bar is increasing.

```
    disableButtons();

    // loop and animate the progress bar
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        Game.setProgBar_loading(i);

        // wait a number of milliseconds
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    }

    enableButtons();
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in a separate thread?

Comment: It was my understanding that Thread.sleep() would freeze the GUI otherwise.

Comment: Fair enough. So why not just re-enable your buttons after the for loop in that thread?

Comment: Because later on, I will have many uses for the Progress Bar. I would like the thread to return true (or any indication) once it's actually finished .

Comment: It sounds to me like what you want is an event listener.  You can make your progress bar code send an event to notify of the bar being completed. Here's the tutorials page on those: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest `Loading` class in `Program` and then access `Program`'s variables from there, and then pretty much copy this part of the code: `// <TODO> re-enable all buttons` into the end of the loop. Something like this:

```
class Program {
    // assuming you have these buttons:
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;

    // snip

    public Program() {

        // assuming there's initialization code for the above buttons somewhere...
        // button1 = new ...
        // button2 = new ...
        // button3 = new ...

        // frame initializing
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setBounds(100, 100, 890, 480);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

        // create the loading bar
        loadingBar = new JProgressBar();
        loadingBar.setBounds(10, 11, 864, 23);
        getContentPane().add(loadingBar);

        // <TODO> disable all buttons
        button1.setEnabled(false);
        button2.setEnabled(false);
        button3.setEnabled(false);

        // animate the loading bar
        Loading thread = new Loading();
        new Thread(thread).start();

        // do not re-enable the buttons here yet.
    }

    // snip

    public class Loading implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // loop and increment loading bar's value
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                Program.setProgressBar(i);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            }

            // re-enable the buttons here instead
            button1.setEnabled(true);
            button2.setEnabled(true);
            button3.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To generalize your `Loading` class and reuse it later you could create an interface that contains methods such as `beforeExecute()` and `afterExecute()`. Take that interface as an argument to `Loading`'s constructor and save it as a member so you can later call the interface's methods from within `run()`:

```
public interface LoadingHandler {
    public void beforeExecute();
    public void afterExecute();
}

public class Loading implements Runnable {
    private LoadingHandler handler;

    public Loading(LoadingHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // disableButtons();
        // use interface's methods instead:
        handler.beforeExecute();

        // loop and animate the progress bar
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            Game.setProgBar_loading(i);

            // wait a number of milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        }

        // enableButtons();
        // use interface's method instead:
        handler.afterExecute();
    }
}
```

Then, in your GUI's thread you would do something like this:

```
Loading thread = new Loading(new LoadingHandler() {
    @Override
    public void beforeExecute() {
        disableButtons();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterExecute() {
        enableButtons();
    }
});

new Thread(thread).start();
```

Comment: That would work, but I don't want the Loading class to be strictly related to re-enabling buttons. Isn't there a way for the Loading class to return true once finished?

Comment: @LawrenceLelo Threads cannot return a value - where will they return it to? Instead you could take an arbitrary function as an argument in `Loading`, and that will act as an event handler for when the thread finishes. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just enable the buttons after the loading bar hits the 100%? Either you do it via callback or just put the regarding code in the `setProgressBar` method

```
// set the progress bar's value
public static void setProgressBar(int num) {
    loadingBar.setValue(num);
    if(num >=100){
       // <TODO> re-enable all buttons
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sur to understand why it is needed to use a thread to animate a progress bar if no parrallel actions are done meanwhile.

**join** method from Thread class is blocking until the thread execution terminates.

```
...
Thread animatedProgressBarThread = new Thread(thread);
animatedProgressBarThread.start();
// next line blocks until thread terminates its execution
animatedProgressBarThread.join();
```

The **run** method of the **Loading** class uses Catch block to ignore InterruptedException. According to documentation, the thread created won't be interruptable. the catch block should set thread's state as interrupted and terminate.

Comment: This will block the GUI, won't it?  (see my comment and his response on the question)